# TemplateDoesNotExist at / on Heroku while working on local server

Tags: python, django, templates, heroku

New to Django and Heroku;

I get "TemplateDoesNotExist at /" when loading the page. Have read somewhere that it might have something to do with Caps.

My template is called templates.

In settings.py :

```
from pathlib import Path
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent 
print(BASE_DIR)
print(BASE_DIR / 'templates')
```

And

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates'],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
```

]

here's my views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
# Create your views here.
def homepage_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
print(args)
print(request.user)
return render(request, "homepage.html",{})
```

HOWEVER

in the error, I get :
"django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: /app/**Templates**/homepage.html (Source does not exist)"

It seems like Heroku doesn't upload the changes I've made to settings.py even though I get "Everything up-to-date"

Everybody seems to be using os.path.join but my Pathlib is working correctly (I assume).

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: Hi! Does the site work locally? Can you post your python view where the html is referenced?

Comment: Did you restart Django on Heroku? Only local development server is restarting automatically after the code changes.

Comment: @sur.la.route, Yep, the site works locally. I've edited the post and added the view.py

Comment: @GwynBleidD, Not sure what you mean by that, but I did git init>status> git add -a> git push heroku main >>>> Everything is up to date; should I commit as well ?

Comment: you could use `logging` or normal file to safe information during running - and then you could check what you have in variables and also what gives `os.listdir()` to see what you have on disk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the reason;

I couldn't commit the changes while having VS Code open. maybe it was a thing regarding only the first commit.

Now able to commit without having to close VS Code.

thanks to those who tried to help.